# Is there any way for Decrypt Password in aspnet_Membership table?

Tags: c#, sql, encryption, asp.net-membership, decoding

I forgot password of admin.I must add new user for web application.

I dont know which method is encrypted for password in aspnet_Membership  table.

E.g

```
select * from aspnet_Membership where UserId='5c908238-f526-4f4c-aac6-a4b284483137'
```

Password : zEttVSSsEktBXeAHKiB+ihtD9OY=

PasswordSalt : v20qOhDVPnwzY8KPimy9XA==

In web.config

```
     <membership defaultProvider="eaMemberShipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
<providers>

    <add name="eaMemberShipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web,
   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 

    connectionStringName="MyDB" 
   enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 

   requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
    applicationName="MyApplication" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" 

    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
     minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 

      passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />

  </providers>
    </membership>
```

And I tried Decrypt  by a program in C# like this

```
    public static string EncodePasswordToBase64(string password)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] encData_byte = new byte[password.Length];
            encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);
            return encodedData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error in base64Encode" + ex.Message);
        }
    }


    public string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

        System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();

        byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);

        int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
        char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
        utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
        string result = new String(decoded_char);
        return result;
    }


   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox3.Text = DecodeFrom64(textBox2.Text);
    }
```

For this password zEttVSSsEktBXeAHKiB+ihtD9OY=

Textbox3=  �KmU$�KA]�* ~�C�

Answer (score 4):

The password isn't stored, only a hash of the password. This ensures that when someone get's hold of your database, this person can't figure out everyone's password. You need to change or reset the password of the user you want to access.

If you want to change the password, there are several methods available. For instance you could run

```
MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser(username);
string resetPwd = usr.ResetPassword();
usr.ChangePassword(resetPwd, newPassword);
```

Refer to [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/admin/recovering-and-changing-passwords-cs) for a more complete list.

Comment: How can I reset password of which I want user ? I have only one admin user and I forgot password.